# Android HttpURLConnection cannot redirect to "market://details?id=my.package.name"

Tags: android, google-play, httpurlconnection

I am launching a HttpURLConnection from my Android device that points my server i.e. **http://example.com/download-app**. The server receives this request and issues a redirect to **market://details?id=my.package.name**. The aim is to have the Android Market app on the phone open and navigate to the app download page.

However, this doesn't seem to work. I set redirects to true on the HttpURLConnection i.e.

```
HttpURLConnection.setFollowRedirects(true);
```

but the URL I receive back is always the same URL to my server i.e. **http://example.com/download-app**.

If I use a redirect link using the "http" protocol like **http://market.android.com/details?id=my.package.name**, it works but instead opens up the new web based market NOT the app on the phone.

Has anyone else experienced this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The aim is to have the Android Market app on the phone open and navigate to the app download page.

Then why are you using `HttpUrlConnection`?

If you want to view a Web page, use an `ACTION_VIEW` `Intent`:

```
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://example.com/download-app")));
```

Comment: @user605333: Android can handle the redirect for you. Just hand it your original URL in the `Intent`.

Comment: @CommonsWare: I need to supply certain parameters to my server, so I have been inserting fields into the HttpHeader, this is why I have been using an HttpUrlConnection to get the redirect link and then using this link for the Intent URI. I cant simply put "http://example.com/download-app" into the URI as I need those parameters to calculate the redirect link.

Thanks

Comment: Looking at my logs I can see it's failing as Android cannot understand the "market" protocol:

`02-06 15:33:36.977: WARN/App(2804): java.net.MalformedURLException: Unknown protocol: market`

Comment: @user605333: Your assessment is incorrect. `java.net` knows nothing about `market`. Android, in the context of `ACTION_VIEW`, knows about `market`. I would nuke the headers and put the data in `GET` parameters or as part of the path, then use `ACTION_VIEW` directly without `HttpUrlConnection`.

Comment: @CommonsWare: I shall add them as Get parameters in that case and see if solves the issue. On a side note, I just noticed if I use "http://market.android.com/details?id=my.package.name" it is changed to use https and not http. Any idea why this is? At the moment the browser opens with a security certificate warning!

Comment: @user605333: Presumably, it is tied to the new Android Market site, but that's just a guess.

Comment: Using a GET request and appending the params to the URL has solved the issue. I can now use market:// to open the Market app automatically and the http://marke... request opens the browser albeit with a security warning. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

If you you to direct to the market use the market url.

```
final Intent marketIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
     Uri.parse(http://market.android.com/details?id=my.package.name));
startActivity(marketIntent);
```

This should open the Market app on a phone.